# How can I directly access methods from my library class in other classes? Java

Tags: java, class, methods

I have a utility class called Tools. In another class, how can I directly assess the methods from Tools without making the method `static` and having the `Tools.methodName();` prefix?

Instead, I'd like to just be able to write `methodName();` and have this work. I know you can use

```
import packagename.Tools
```

but my IDE still wants me to change the method to `static`. So for example:

Utility class:

```
package jsmash;

public class Tools {
    public boolean expect(char c, int i) {
        return Filler.fileContents[i] == c;
    }
}
```

What I'd like to be able to do:**

```
package jsmash
import jsmash.Tools;
public class Test {
    void use() { 
        expect('c', 32); // directly call the expect method without *Tools.* prefix
    }
}
```

Comment: And yes, I know, I'm about to be marked for a duplicate. That helps too. I couldn't find one on my own so I'm good with that.

Comment: The method has to be static and then you can use static import.

Comment: @pvg ok give me a minute I'm googling that.

Comment: Use inheritance? ex: `public class Test extends Tools { //stuff }`?

Comment: @pvg can you provide an example of using the static import for my situation? Thanks!

Comment: @RileyCarney clever. Didn't exactly think of that. It might work, although I'd rather not use inheritance for structure purposes.

Comment: To do a static imput (with quick google search) I found `import static jsmash.Tools.expect;`

Comment: To call it afterwords, you can simply do `expect(char c, int i)`. However, it is discouraged as a program structure because it makes programs extremely unreadable after a couple of static imports, because you're not sure where the method is coming from. Tl;dr: Be wary of using it.

Comment: @RileyCarney yup thanks. Bohemian gave me an example too. I'm accepting that one. Also, thanks for the tip. I'm only using this static import for one class. (Because I'm using the methods in that class a whole lot)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make the method `static`
2. Statically import the method

Like this:

```
public class Tools {
    public static boolean expect(char c, int i) { //dont worry about what this method is actually doing
        if(Filler.fileContents[i] == c) return true;
        else return true;

    }
}
```

Then to use:

```
import static jsmash.Tools.expect;
public class Test {
    void use() { 
       expect('c', 32);
    }
}
```

You can also simply:

```
import static jsmash.Tools.*;
```

To bulk import all static methods (and fields).

Comment: Thank you! Perfect. Also @pvg you were saying the same thing.

Comment: Umm... *without making the method `static`*?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yeah sorry my fault. The reason I said that was because I thought the only way static worked was by adding the prefix when you need to reference. I didn't know that static import let me do this.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch basically, that was my lack of knowledge-of Java talking.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you don't have to add `import jsmash.Tools;` because Tools and Test class are in the same package. But if there is a connection between Tools and Test(Test IS-A Tools) you can achieve this by simply extending the Test class (inheritance)

```
package jsmash
public class Test extends Tools{
    void use() { 
       expect('c', 32);
    }

}
```

Comment: Read the comments of the body. See @Riley Carney's comments.